# Auto Serial Number in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have summary report Group by Location & sum of Value for that Location is displayed. I want Serial No to be automatically generated . I am using RowNumber("DataSet_Result") but it id display values like 5,30,543,548 . For each location there is 1 row

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SQL Server as a data source, I would add a RANK() based on Location to the code and then display that in the report

Answer (score 0):

You could use RunningValue function in your expression.